# Will updates and security updates update my Ubuntu version?

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

When logging into my VPS, it says there are some updates and security updates, however; because I'm not that into Ubuntu programming, I prefer staying onto 12.04 LTS. Therefor I was wondering: Do updates change my Ubuntu version to 13.x or any other version or will I stay on 12.04, until I manually update?

Just like Windows, I could think that it would only change the third, hidden digest of the Ubuntu, as, e.g. I'm currently on 12.04.120 and after the update, I will be onto 12.04.385

Just to be sure.. :) - Please clarify, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update vs Upgrade.

No.

Updates do not change your version.  To change version, it will ask if you want upgrade.

Comment: IIRC, the LTS releases won't ask you to upgrade until the next LTS comes out, although I could be wrong.   I do know for sure that I'm still using 12.04 and I update on a pretty regular basis.

Comment: Would you recommend to update only security updates, for 'non-geeks' or can I safely update all packages?

Comment: That depends on what you're using the computer for.  Non-security updates either fix bugs or add new functionality.  They will also occasionally introduce new bugs.  If you're using the computer for something very specific that ***MUST*** always work (and is currently working), then skip the other updates.  For general computing, I would say an update is more likely to help for more often than hinder.

Comment: For my part, I use the computer for work each day, and I install all updates...

Comment: I use Ubuntu as a webserver, for my mail services, databases and web hosting. Which always must work, therefor, indeed: Only update what's necessary: Security. - Right? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12419/discussion-between-david-oneill-and-sander-schaeffer)